# Entity manager changes detached entities

Tags: spring, jpa, testing, kotlin, entitymanager

Help me.

Why does the collection in the entity change after the transaction?

My entity:

```
@Entity
class Entity(
  @Id
  val uuid: UUID,

  @OneToMany(cascade = [CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REMOVE])
  @JoinTable(
    name = "entities_items",
    joinColumns = [JoinColumn(name = "entity_uuid")],
    inverseJoinColumns = [JoinColumn(name = "item_uuid")]
  )
  val items: MutableList<Item>
)
```

My test:

```
@SpringBootTest
internal class EntityTest {
  @Autowired
  lateinit var entityRepository: EntityRepository

  @Autowired
  lateinit var transactionManager: PlatformTransactionManager

  @Test
  fun will_added_item() {
    val entityBefore = entityRepository.findById(entityId).get()
    // entityBefore.items.size == 0

    TransactionTemplate(transactionManager).execute { _ ->
      val entity = entityRepository.findById(entityId).get()

      entity.items.add(item)
    }

    // entityBefore.items.size == 1 <-- ???
    val entityAfter = entityRepository.findById(entityId).get()
  }
}
```

Interestingly, if I add any call to the collection before the transaction, everything will be fine.

Spring Boot + Hibernate + JUnit

Comment: https://www.javatpoint.com/kotlin-mutablelist-mutablelistof
you add item in the list; pls check the documentation

Comment: Yes, but these are different collections. Or I don't understand something...

Comment: Different references*

Answer (score 0):

- please ignore this wrong answer - can't seem to delete it on my phone!

This is because when you retrieve an item by id within a transaction multiple times, Hibernate will give you same object as it is managing the objects involved in the transaction as a unit of work.

Hence entityBefore and entity are pointing at the same object.

Ah sorry, ignore that - I see first retrieval was outside the tx!

Comment: Interestingly, if I add any call to the collection before the transaction, everything will be fine.

Comment: Hmm - interesting, will have a quick read up on that. Presumably in the test entityBefore and entity are pointing to the same object but that's just bizarre behaviour - though not the first time I've hit odd stuff in Hibernate

Comment: Hmm ... more oddities! If in debug mode stop execution before the transaction and continue, everything will be fine.

Comment: Just looking at Persistence Bag, this is the unintuitive thing where Hibernate replaces your collection type with it's own - cropped up in a recent question where someone had a Sorted collection type but was a bit thrown because Hibernate used an Unsorted collection. Doesn't explain why Hibernate appears to be managing an entity that is outside the transaction in the same unit as that inside

Comment: Persistence Bag is just an assumption. I do not know why this is happening :( After all, each transaction has its own persistence context. This means that all special types should not affect external code.

Comment: Just thinking, in the test maybe there is an implicit transaction and then the new TransactionTemplate execution creates a nested transaction so in the same hibernate unit. Have you got the whole test source?

Comment: But your stop when debugging is very odd, but probably a big clue as it makes no sense and hence is probably where the answer lies

Comment: I changed my test example.

Comment: It seems to me that my breakpoint before the transaction is just a way to resolve proxies. The same effect can be achieved by adding instructions before the transaction, which will access the collection.

Comment: Just to completely clarify - if before the transaction you maybe add a couple of items to entityBefore.items, then after the transaction entityBefore.items still just has 2? Have you turned up log level to have a look at what queries are being run, and that might not help so maybe next a breakpoint in some of the Hibernate code. On the face of it it sounds like if you dirty that entity outside tx, then tx entity is isolated but if you don't then tx just gets a reference to that one.

Comment: Actually, the hibernate context is related to the session which does encompass your whole test. The transaction is just one transaction inside that session. I think it starts to make sense then. The entityBefore is in the context and when you start transaction, if that entity is not dirty then no reason to use a separate instance. I guess this is documented somewhere.

Comment: If I do before the transaction: 

val item = Item();
entityBefore.items.add(item);
entityBefore.items.remove(item);

Everything will work, but I don’t understand why.

Comment: Maybe even adding and removing item marks the entity as dirty and forces the transaction to get the persisted version rather than the current session managed version. The exact details will be somewhere in https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/transactions.html but I'm heading off to sleep now. No decisive answer as yet but I think this may be the cause.

Comment: It looks implicit and wrong. If it's true. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I often hate Hibernate, because of stuff like this and the slow startup times. The only reason I'm slightly reluctant to switch back to mybatis or straight JDBCTemplate is the nice optimistic lock conflict detection that's done for you. Apart from that, what did JPA implementations ever do for us except give us grief!